# CSS selector specificity and file load order

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a page with two different stylesheets. one.css is loaded before second.css

In one.css this selector is found:

```
  a.utility__block--booking-link {
        color: #fff;
    }
```

In second.css this selector is found:

```
a, a:visited {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: inherit;
}
```

On page load the a, a:visited {} selector is in effect, even though a.utility__block--booking-link is more specific. Does file load order actually take precedence over selector specificity?

Comment: What do you need ? please explain your need of this code

Comment: I need the class selector to be in effect and no the a: visited. But I guess :visited is more specific than a class selector in the css spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we know the css works as the last come first serve order, i.e the code you write last is in precidence, in your case the css of `a.utility__block--booking-link` in one.css is overwritten by the css of `a, a:visited` from second.css as per the css stylesheet rules, so if you place the second.css before the one.css then actually reverse of this will happen.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just needed to change to this

```
a.utility__block--booking-link,a:visited.utility__block--booking-link {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Since :visited is more specific than a class selector.